# What did Kakashi/Sakura mean in this scenario? Naruto Shippuden Ep 484

Tags: naruto

https://youtu.be/V0zyVCjld9M

Ep 484 of Naruto Shippuden. "Exploding people"

Kakashi says "good observation", but neither of them verbally say it.
What did Sakura say without wording it?

> Kakashi: Whoever did it, the genjutsu is unknown to us. It has to be
>   the work of someone with extraordinary skill. So it will require someone
>   with extraordinary Visual Jutsu powers.
>
> Sakura: *looks at Kakashi, startled*
>
> Kakashi : (noticing) Good observation.
>
> Sakura : I didn't say anything. *blush*
>
> Then she punches Naruto offscreen for asking about it.
>
> Kakashi: We might not see anything, but a person with the Sharingan and
>   Rinnegan might.

Comment: Please provide more details and don't depend on people watching a video

Comment: @JoeW Thanks Joe I added more detail. I understood the reference now. That video is not providing enough context, I had to watch a bit more from the episode. What do I do now? Now it looks like a lame question. Yep looks like it lacked research. So should I flag it?

Comment: You could post that as an answer but that is all up to you. The main reason I posted my comment is that not everyone is in a position to watch a video but they might be able to provide an answer from a description.

Comment: @Pavan: If you were able to figure out the answer yourself, you're more than welcome to self-answer the question. Others might find it useful.

Comment: So hear Sakura is thinking about Sasuke(because sharingan genjutsu is the best) hence the entire scenario plays out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ep 484 happens after Naruto the last movie.
Prelude to which Sasuke(Sakura's husband) goes away from the village to gather info on Kaguya and help others on his way.
He's has been distant to his family, so Sakura is excited about him being back.

Because he's diligent about helping the village and he's the one with highest visual jutsu prowess, She knew he'd come to help. She's shy about reveling her excitement.